# How to configure Filebeat to read log files, using ELK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, filebeat, elk

I am new to nowadays ELK stack.

I need to have an ability to read logs from path, using ElasticSearch, Kibana and Filebeat.
I've tried to configure them step by step with ELK guides. But I still cannot see my logs in Kibana.

Now I work only with localhost.

Here is how my .yml files are configured:

elasticsearch.yml:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

kibana.yml:

```
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: "elastic1"
```

filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\\logs\\*.log


- type: filestream
  enabled: false
  paths:
    - C:\logs\*

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1


setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"
  username: "kibana_system"
  password: "kibana_system1"


output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "elastic1"
setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"

processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```

So I execute ElasticSearch and Kibana. It's OK. I set up Filebeat, using PowerShell like in guide. Many dashboards are being loaded. But I can't see anything, related to my logs in `Discovery` tab...

Tell me, please, if I do anything wrong, or may be I need to configure the files more deeply?

Comment: From Dev Tools, are you able to see if your `filebeat-xyz` index is actually receiving data?

Comment: @Val, I've opened DevTools and sent default request, which has been already typed, and got the answer, which is on the right panel. So, I think, yes)

Comment: Ok, did you create an index pattern `filebeat-*` that you can use in the Discover application?

Comment: @Val, Yes, I did. It's called `filebeat-*`

Comment: And you picked the proper date field (e.g. `@timestamp`)?

Comment: @Val, Yes, timestamp

Comment: So you're all set, in Discover, you can adjust the time picker to select the right time window of your logs

Comment: @Val, Didn't help, I've set last 300 days...

Comment: Can you hit the "Inspect" button and copy/paste the query that you're seeing?

Comment: @Val, it's too long, cannot be pasted into comment. Or may be you mean to send not Request, but Response?

Comment: You can update your question with it